# Dealing with update from database using a list

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have a problem in dealing with update from database using a list, in edit class I have this method

```
private ArrayList<store> store_List = new ArrayList<store>();
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        store store = store_List.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(edit.this,Update.class);
        edit.this.finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In Update class, I have this method:

```
  btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DB db = new DB(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                    db.open();
                    db.updatestore(HERE WHAT SHOULD I PASS);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (SQLiteException se) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                            "Could not create or Open the database");
                } finally {
                    if (db != null)
                        db.close();

                }
        }
    });
```

In DB, the method update is as follow:

```
   public int updatestore(store s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, s.getName());
    values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, s.getCategory());
    return db.update(TABLE_store, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(s.getEid()) });
   }
```

Comment: what kind of error do you become?

Comment: I have no error I just want to know what should I pass in db.updatestore(HERE);

Comment: Yes, I saw it, one moment and I'll write you my suggestion as an answer

Comment: Your updatestore() method takes a `store` variable. So you have to pass a `store` variable there first. After updating your database get all data from database and pass those values to your adapter then call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the store item you have selected from the store_List to your Update.class like this:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        store store = store_List.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(edit.this,Update.class);
        intent.putExtra("myStore", store);
        edit.this.finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

and then in your Update.class you could get the store item like this:

```
Store passedStore = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myStore");
```

and then in your onCLickListener you will have the following:

```
btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DB db = new DB(getApplicationContext());
        try {
                db.open();
                db.updatestore(passedStore);  //the store item you became as an extra from your intent
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (SQLiteException se) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "Could not create or Open the database");
            } finally {
                if (db != null)
                    db.close();

            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you .. When I write Store passedStore = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myStore"); An error occurred telling to Add cast to store or change type of passedScore to Serializable. What should I do?

Comment: implement Serilizable in your `Store` class.

Comment: try type casting `Store passedStore = (Store)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myStore"); `

Comment: 05-23 13:46:59.979: E/AndroidRuntime(20754): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInf{com.example.storesystem/com.example.storesystem.Update}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 13:46:59.979: E/AndroidRuntime(20754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
05-23 13:46:59.979: E/AndroidRuntime(20754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)